# JAVASCRIPT- iOS keyboard "prev","next" active/inactive

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, keyboard

I have two text fields `(input type="text")` say `#tb1,#tb2`
Now the second textbox appears only if I enter a particular string in the first text box *(some serial number)*

Now I'm accessing the web application with an iPad so when I tap on the first text field the native iOS keyboard pops out. With "prev" (active) & "next" (inactive) on top of the keyboard.

Now when I enter the correct serial number in the first text field, the second text field appears. But the "next" button in the iPad keyboard is not in an active state. I need this because after the user has entered the correct string in the first text field he will tap on the "next" button which will bring the focus on the second text field for the user to enter data.

Is there any way in Javascript to tell the native iOS keyboard that the 2nd text field is now visible & enable the "next" button. In other words can i refresh the native iOS keyboard "view" when the 2nd text field is visible.

I did some Googling and found that to call/dismiss the iOS keyboard in objective-C can be done by:

```
becomeFirstResponder [myTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

Not sure how this thing works in objective C.

I'm looking for a javascript solution to refresh the iOS keyboard so that when the 2nd textfield is visible the "next" button is active and vice-versa.

Any other JS/iOS solution is also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply focus on the second field after it has become visible and the first one was filled. That's no brainer with JQuery, and the iOS browser will happily enable the "back" button on the keyboard when you auto-focus on the next field:

```
window.onload = function () {
    $('#tb1').keyup(function(evt){
        if(evt.target.value == 'CORRECT_SERIAL_NUMBER') {
            $('#tb2').show();
            $('#tb2').focus();
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks Tal,But the problem is even if i focus in the 2nd textfield the native iOS keyboard's "next" button doesn't get active. It is only after i dismiss the keyboard & then open the keyboard again (by tapping on any textfield) the "next" button of the iOS keyboard becomes active.

Comment: the desired behavior should be the "next" button should become active as soon as the 2nd textfield becomes visible.So that i use "next" button to go to #tb2

Comment: Moreover if i focus the 2nd textfield ($("#tb2").focus()) the iOS keyboard doesn't stays, rather gets dismissed and will not return back unless & until i tap back on any field.

Comment: I have created a test project and web page and it works well inside a UIWebView, but not in iOS safari:
http://tal.yaniv.info/tests/test06.zip

Comment: Yes i'm testing on iOS Safari. Any clue on that?

Comment: Sorry, no. Only visible text fields activate keyboard.

Comment: you mean when a textfield becomes visible there is no way that we can send a notification to the native iOS keyboard that there is a new text field & activate the "next" button for reaching to it?

Comment: Define "native iOS keyboard". If your target is standard iOS Safari, it opens the keyboard per user interaction and enable the back/next buttons depending on available focus items. I found this hack. It's ugly and not a good practice: https://discussions.apple.com/message/17518933#17518933. If the target is an app that you develop, you have wider control as demonstrated in the test project above. You cannot invoke native iOS API calls from a Safari web page with html/javascript whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks for the help Tal. By native iOS keyboard i mean the keyboard displayed by iOS when we tap any text field.Moreover is there no bridge between native iOS APIs & javascript?

Comment: No, it's similar to a desktop browser with no extension/plugin capability.